# Placing controls outside map container with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Can someone tell me how I can place controls outside of the map content with Leaflet?

In this case, I just want to place the layer switch control outside the map object.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Leaflet does a lot of hand-waving to hide implementation of the map portal but lucky for you they have thought of a solution!

The [`getContainer`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-getcontainer) function is just what you need.
This returns the actual HTML node, not just the markup.

It is then just as easy as un-childing(?) the node and assign it to a new parent, with a couple lines of Javascript.

Working example and comments (and a kick-ass tileset)!

http://codepen.io/romahicks/pen/ONmPmp

**The Code**

```
//Create Layer
var baseMap = new    L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/gvenech.m13knc8e/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'   );

var baseMapIndex = {
  "Map": baseMap
};

// Create the map
var map = new L.map('map', {
  center: new L.LatLng(41.019829, 28.989864),
  zoom: 14,
  maxZoom: 18,
  zoomControl: false, // Disable the default zoom controls.
  layers: baseMap
});

// Create the control and add it to the map;
var control = L.control.layers(baseMapIndex);
control.addTo(map);

 // Call the getContainer routine.
 var htmlObject = control.getContainer();
 // Get the desired parent node.
 var a = document.getElementById('new-parent');

 // Finally append that node to the new parent, recursively searching out and re-parenting nodes.
 function setParent(el, newParent)
 {
    newParent.appendChild(el);
 }
 setParent(htmlObject, a);
```

You must recursively go through all the children and reassign them to their parent.  See the second answer for a simple recursive loop.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910147/how-to-move-all-html-element-children-to-another-parent-using-javascript

Comment: Nice work. Already up-voted you, but would you mind adding the relevant JavaScript to your answer?

Comment: `a.appendChild(control.onAdd(map))` should be enough. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041651/leaflet-put-controls-outside-the-div-map

Comment: It worked well with the getContainer solution. But when i tried with the a.appendChild(control.onAdd(map)), all the wms layers and layer control disappear.

Comment: I update my answer with a recursive loop to get children, sorry.  Please let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @mauriciosantos My bad, it does not work as simply for `L.control.layers`.

Comment: Hello Guys. That code works with various leaflet controls but when i try it with "leaflet tree layer control", doesn't work. Someone can explain me why?

Answer (score 1):

Simple possible way i have used:

Add below html tag, where you want move the leaflet controls:

```
<div id="custom-map-controls"></div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var newParent = document.getElementById('custom-map-controls');
        var oldParent = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-top leaflet-right")

        while (oldParent[0].childNodes.length > 0) {
            newParent.appendChild(oldParent[0].childNodes[0]);
        }
 });
```